# Get excel to paste the entire row in the next available spot on a new worksheet instead of overwriting the data already there

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code to copy/paste an entire row if a column contains a keyword. I assigned the macro to a button. It works, but if I get a new item that is marked complete and press the button again, it erases everything on the 'Complete' worksheet and pastes the new information. I want it to paste it under the last row.

```
    Dim i As long
    Dim p As long
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet

    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("In Progress")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Complete")

    p = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
    Dim lastrow As Integer: lastrow = Source.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    For i = lastrow To 3 Step -1
        If Source.Range("B" & i).Value = "Complete" Then
        Source.Rows(i).Copy Target.Rows(p)
        Source.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        p = p + 1
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

After Googling, it appears I need something like

`lastrow = Sheet2.Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row + 1.`

Am I somewhat close to what I need to solve it? Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in finding last used cell in Excel with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba)

Comment: Don't use `Integer` either, use `Long`.

Comment: Yes I tested it and it wasn't working for me so I was posting to know if I was even on the right track.

Comment: Thank you BigBen. I will read that and see if I can solve it.

Comment: Your problem is that you are using `p = 3` to start your paste to the `Target` sheet. So when you re-initiate the macro again, it will overwrite every row on the `Target` sheet.  You will need to dimension a different last row variable for each worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working version:

```
Sub TransferComplete()
    Dim i As long
    Dim p As long
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet

    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("In Progress")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Complete")

    p = Target.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1    ' Start copying to last row in target sheet
    Dim lastrow As long: lastrow = Source.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    For i = lastrow To 3 Step -1
        If Source.Range("B" & i).Value = "Complete" Then
        Source.Rows(i).Copy Target.Rows(p)
        Source.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        p = p + 1
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

I removed `p = 3` and replaced it with `p = Target.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1`